# Prove that if a function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is bijective then $\forall M \gt 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N ,\forall n \geq N, f(n) \geq M$

Tags: functions

The only indication I have is to consider $\max(f^{-1}(\{0..M\}))$

Comment: Well, given $M$, for example $M=5$, how many $n$ can there be such that $f(n) < 5$?

Comment: $f(n)={0..4}$ and $f$ bijective so 5 $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}(\{0,\dotsc,M\})$ is the set of numbers such that $f(n)\leq M$, so, every number $n$ that is not in this set satiesfies $f(n)\geq M$.

The set $f^{-1}(\{0,\dotsc,M\})$ has $M+1$ elements as $f$ is bijective, so is bounded and $\max\{f^{-1}(\{0,\dotsc,M\})\}$ is finite, then, every number $n\geq\max\{f^{-1}(\{0,\dotsc,M\})\}$ satisfies that $f(n)\geq M$.

Then, $N=\max\{f^{-1}(\{0,\dotsc,M\})\}$ is the number we were looking after.

Answer (score 1):

If there doesn't exist such an $N$ for a given $M$, then there's an infinite, strictly increasing sequence $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ such that $f(n_i)<M$, for each $i$. Now invoke the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Alex.Nice answer.